# RemoteCertificateChainErrors - Empty ChainElementStatus C#

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, tls1.2

Strange issue happening intermittently whereby my HTTPS call to another service results in an exception being thrown (Underlying channel closed, remote certificate invalid according to callback...etc).

I'm hosting .net core (461) inside an azure app service.

My SSL certificate on the service being consumed is a public CA (GeoTrust/Digicert) certificate, and the same calls work almost all of the time, but I get periods when they routinely fail without any code change or deployments.

The strange part is, I supplied my own delegate (ServerCertificateValidationCallback) to skim the details of the certificate being returned, its chain, policy errors, etc - and when I get the error, the SSLPolicyError is set to RemoteCertificateChainErrors, yet when iterating over the ChainElements of the X509Chain, it returns a single element (my certificate) - and the ChainElementStatus is empty, with no corresponding deep-dive detail as to why the remote chain was considered invalid, it just states that it is.

I have compared this to an automated test using badssl.com as a test bed and I correctly get full chain details, including the reason as to why one of the elements was considered bad.

What possible reason could cause a RemoteCertificateChainErrors SSLPolicyError without having any corresponding chain information? Could it be a piece of networking kit has failed to call the CA itself to assess validity of the certificate?

Most strange error, appreciate any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We finally resolved this, by having to include the intermediate certificate alongside our ssl certificate on the service end. We still think the issue is in the failure to verify the intermediate certificate remotely in good time when not included in the bundle, but have yet to verify this.